# AdMob: Could not find auto-linked framework 'FBLPromises'

Tags: objective-c, xcode, admob

I have a Objective C project and I want to add AdMob to it. Been following https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/quick-start#objective-c

I get the linker error 
ld: warning: Could not find auto-linked framework 'FBLPromises'
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIScene"

I'm adding the frameworks manually. I dragged them in.

The tutorial doesn't say anything about the promises framework, but it comes in their download. And if I don't add it, I get a linker error saying a function is missing.

All of the frameworks are in the project and in Link With Binary Libraries list.

I tried deleting them and re-adding them, and quitting Xcode and clean build.

I tried adding framework search paths $(inherited) and $(TOOLCHAIN_DIR)/usr/lib/swift/$(PLATFORM_NAME) and the folder they are in with recursive $(PROJECT_DIR)/Frameworks and all of their exact paths individually also.

I tried adding a new swift file to the project so that it becomes hybrid.

I added -ObjC linker flag to Other Linker Flags, and $(inherited)

The tutorial says to add "GoogleUtilities.framework" But what I downloaded has "GoogleUtilities.xcframework" folder. So I tried adding the folder both as a group and as not, and I tried adding the framework files in the folder only.

I tried making a new project with nothing else.

Can anyone get AdMob to work on an Objective C project with adding frameworks manually?

I have agreed to the latest terms from apple and have a paid developer account.

Comment: I'm seeing this as well. It seems like they're missing a framework in their "manual install" package, or the PromisesObjC.xcframework is misconfigured. I'll reach out to them to investigate.

Answer (score 21):

I had a similar error in a Swift project.

```
Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_JSContext
```

In my case the solution was to add the JavaScriptCore.framework to the project.

Comment: In my case I did not need it.

Comment: Thanks for this.  This resolved my problem.

Comment: It seems that JavaScriptCore.framework is required for iOS 14 SDK.

Comment: Adding JavaScriptCore.framework solved the issue for me

Answer (score 3):

Figured out the issue for a hybrid project!

The project I was linking to used an ObjC Bridging Header, so I simply needed to import Firebase in the header file:

```
// ObjC-Bridging-Header.h
#import "Firebase.h"
```

Not sure if this relates to a pure ObjC project, but you might be able to add a dummy Swift file to make it a hybrid project and use the bridging header.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error. I had forgotten to add the following libs: **nanopb.xcframework**, **PromisesObjC.xcframework**, **UserMessagingPlatform.framework** - included in GoogleMobileAdsSdkiOS.. I just added the missed libraries and now everything is OK.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add **libz.tbd,** **libc++.tbd**, **libsqlite3.tbd** and **StoreKit** libraries in Link Binary With Libraries at the Build Phases tab.